# How do I reveal hidden/obscured text in VMware Horizon Client (Linux)?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, themes, vmware, gtk

## Description

When I open certain menus in VMware Horizon (Linux), the text is hidden. It seems to me as if the text is falling into the white background due to my system using the Breeze Dark theme rather than light.

### Horizon in Breeze (Light) Theme:

[image: horizon in Breeze theme]

[image: horizon preferences menu in Breeze theme]

### Horizon in Breeze Dark theme:

[image: horizon in Breeze Dark theme]

[image: horizon preferences menu in Breeze Dark theme]

One way to fix this may be to force Horizon to use light mode, but I am unsure how to do this.

### System Info

Operating System: Kubuntu 21.10 
KDE Plasma Version: 5.22.5 
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.86.0 
Qt Version: 5.15.2 
Kernel Version: 5.13.0-22-generic (64-bit) 
Graphics Platform: X11 
Processors: 12 × Intel® Core™ i7-8750H CPU @ 2.20GHz 
Memory: 31.2 GiB of RAM 
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 Ti/PCIe/SSE2

Comment: Try to change the Plasma theme.

Comment: @N0rbert I changed the Plasma theme from Breeze to Breeze Dark -- shown in the question. I want to be able to use the application while using the Breeze Dark theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

I found a VMware support thread covering this issue [here](https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Horizon-Desktops-and-Apps/Color-problem-with-Horizon-Client-in-linux-dark-theme/td-p/1867387). The thread is also available on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20220407181916/https://communities.vmware.com/t5/Horizon-Desktops-and-Apps/Color-problem-with-Horizon-Client-in-linux-dark-theme/td-p/1867387).

According to one of the repsonses, VMware Horizon does not support dark mode. The solution to this is to alter Horizon's `.desktop` file to force the application to use a specific theme.

To workaround the non-support, edit the "Exec" line in `/usr/share/applications/vmware-view.desktop` by adding `env GTK_THEME=<theme_name>` before the rest of the command. Replace `<theme_name>` with a theme on your system. `breeze` worked for me.

[image: vmware horizon desktop file before edit with "Exec" line highlighted]

[image: vmware horizon desktop file after edit with "Exec" line highlighted]

After this edit, text in Horizon should no longer be obscured.

[image: post-edit Horizon with non-obscured text]